# How do I to trigger an AttachmentAdd event?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, email-attachments

I am trying to extract data from an .xlsx file and send Outlook email.

Below is testing code that failed to trigger the MailItem's "AttachmentAdd" event. The msgbox never shows up.
Is it because I am making code in Excel - VBA Project window?

In the Class Moudule: (Class name: ApplicationEventClass2)

```vb
Public WithEvents newItem As Outlook.MailItem

Private Sub newItem_AttachmentAdd(ByVal Attachment As Outlook.Attachment)
MsgBox ("you added an attachment")
End Sub
```

In the moudule: (Moudule name: Moudule1)

```vb
Sub cwOut1()

Dim MyOutlook1 As Object
Set MyOutlook1 = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim newItem As Object
Set newItem = MyOutlook1.CreateItem(olMailItem)

newItem.Display

Dim atts As Outlook.Attachments
 
Dim newAttachment As Outlook.Attachment

newItem.Subject = "Test attachment"
 
Set atts = newItem.Attachments
 
Set newAttachment = atts.Add("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test.txt", olByValue)

End Sub
```

************code corrected 20230515**********

In the moudule: (Moudule name: Moudule1)

```vb
Sub cwOut1()
Dim aa123 As MailItem
Set aa123 = CreateItem(olMailItem)
Dim newClass As New ApplicationEventClass2
Set newClass.newItem = aa123
aa123.display

 Dim atts As Outlook.Attachments

 aa123.Subject = "Test attachment"
 
 aa123.Attachments.Add "C:\Users\asdf\Desktop\Test.txt"
 
End Sub
```

I am expecting: In Excel, after I run the Macro Sub "cwOut1", an email automatically drafted with attachment "test.txt" and a Msgbox popup wiht text "you added an attachment".

Comment: Where did you create an instance of `ApplicationEventClass2`?

Comment: Yes, you are right @Rory .   beside missing instance,  I also didn't assign the MailItem to the class. See updated code above. I mixed up the ApplicationEventClass with the ApplicationEventClass.newitem

Answer (score 0):

When I run similar code, I can see the following events fire, `AttachmentAdd` being one of them.

Your code defines `newItem` variable twice - once as a `MailItem` object with event support enabled, and the second time as `object` inside the `cwOut1` sub. Remove the `Dim newItem As Object` declaration.

```
Open (false)
<Unknown(DispID=0x0000FC99)> (false)
AfterWrite ()
<Unknown(DispID=0x0000FC95)> (false)
PropertyChange (UnRead)
PropertyChange (ConversationTopic)
PropertyChange (ConversationIndex)
PropertyChange (Subject)
PropertyChange (InternetCodepage)
BeforeAttachmentWriteToTempFile (IDispatch, false)
BeforeAttachmentAdd (IDispatch, false)
BeforeAttachmentSave (IDispatch, false)
AttachmentAdd (IDispatch)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I found that there are multiple mistakes in my coding.